# Java.util.Arrays.sort - what type?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What type of search is Java.util.Arrays.sort()?  Not important but I was just curious.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is where reading the documentation is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])):

> Implementation note: The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort
>   by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This
>   algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause
>   other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically
>   faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.